# Posts not displaying

Tags: python, django

I have verified that there are entries in the Books table, but my template is not displaying them for a reason I can't seem to pinpoint.

Model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    bookTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    bookURL = models.SlugField() 
    bookContent = models.TextField()
    bookAuthor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,  related_name = 'books')
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for p in books %}
    <div class="post-wrapper col-lg-8 card" style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 20 auto;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title">{{  p.bookTitle  }}</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {{  p.bookContent   }}
            </div>
            <em style="margin-left: 10px;"><small>written by {{  p.bookAuthor  }} at {{  p.creationDate  }}</small></em>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Book
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.

def viewAll(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'viewAll.html', {})
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing any data to the view context - you need to pass the `books` in the context dictionary (third argument):

```
def viewAll(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'viewAll.html', {'books': books}) # <--- this is currently empty
```

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't in the tutorial.

Comment: @errvbreb You should mark this answer as correct as well.